# How can be SKView added to controller's view in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    CGRect screenFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    _controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    _controller.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenFrame];

    SKView *skView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:screenFrame];
    skView.backgroundColor = [SKColor blueColor];
    [_controller.view addSubview:skView];

    self.window.rootViewController = _controller;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

But instead of seeing blue screen I see gray screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an SKScene to be presented from your SKView in order to see the color. Also it is strange to be doing this in the AppDelegate, but maybe not? I have never seen that sort of thing placed there.

I have this and it works fine.

```
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

CGRect screenFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
UIViewController *_controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
_controller.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenFrame];

SKView *skView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:screenFrame];
SKScene *currentScene = [[SKScene alloc]initWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
currentScene.backgroundColor = [SKColor blueColor];
[_controller.view addSubview:skView];
[skView presentScene:currentScene];

self.window.rootViewController = _controller;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;
```

Comment: Just saw that SKView doesn't contain any backgroundColor property ( https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013031 )
I have solved this, but anyway an interesting question.